# Parallel Test Execution - Keyword Driven framework (Eclipse+ Selenium WebDriver + Maven + JAVA + TestNG)

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Can any one suggest a way to implement parallel execution for keyword driven framework which is reading test script names from a main sheet. The keywords are written in sheets with test scripts as its name. Sorry i cannot provide details more than this as it is a client requirement

PS: I have already used data-provider concept which did not match my requirement.

Thank you in advance!! Any help would be great.

Comment: TestNG allow you to execute test cases parallel.

Comment: @HelpingHands Thank you for the reply but the thing is i do not have any classes or XML file for scripts to run them in parallel in TestNG.

Comment: I see , but you can create xml easily.